# Send Slack workflow message to SNS topic subscribers

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, slack, amazon-sns

I have created a workflow(say 'IT support') in a slack  channel (say 'IT-support-weekends') for providing IT support during weekends and after-hours. Please help me understand how to integrate Amazon SNS with Slack so that

- every time a new 'IT support' workflow is added into that slack channel, then all the subscribers to the SNS topic(say 'it-support-topic') get a customized message?

I looked into this [article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams) but it talks about an incoming webhook.